# Who is Major Victory, and why does he have Captain America's shield?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, captain-america, guardians-of-the-galaxy

I was reading the Guardians of the Galaxy volume one and suddenly a character known as **Major Victory** got unfrozen (*same as Captain America*) and he appears to have Captain America's shield.

[image: Major Victory with Captain America's shield]

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vance_Astro#Quest_for_the_Shield_and_release_from_containment_suit - Answer is here.

Comment: My guess is that someday we are going to find out that Vance Astro aka Major Victory is in fact Steve Rogers. I don't know when or how he got frozen again, but that's what happened. maybe he doesn't remember who he is but that's bound to be the case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Do you have anything to back up this guess? Answers which are just unsupported speculation tend to get downvoted and deleted here.

Comment: @user64171 I doubt it.  We've met Vance Astro in the "present day".  He was the Thing's sidekick for a bit between the first and second Secret Wars.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The story you're reading is set substantially into the future. Since Captain America's shield is indestructible, it makes sense that it's still extant.

Per the [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Captain_America%27s_Shield) page on Captain America's Shield;

> **In several alternate timelines, the shield survives and comes to be
>   possessed by other significant individuals.** In late 37th-early 39th
>   century, Nathan Dayspring and Tetherbood lead a squad of the Clan
>   Rebellion to obtain the shield, which Nathan used to inspire liberty
>   and justice in his followers and bore into many battles, until it was
>   ripped from his arm.
>
> **On Earth-691, Major Victory acted on rumor and legend to find the
>   shield, which he used as a symbol to rally the warring people of Earth
>   after they were freed from the conquering Badoon in the 31st century.**

[image]

Comment: You down voted but still answered the question, interesting...

Comment: @secko - I downvoted because I felt that it was a lazy question. You'll note that it's basically a copy/paste answer.

Comment: I could quote meta here where it says that questions like these are welcomed. Was I lazy to search, yes. I wanted to know the answer quick so I could continue reading. If this site is here only for deep minded questions and answers than I won't be apart of that.

Comment: @Secko - I classify a question as lazy when you could google the actual question title and be instantly presented with the answer. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vance+astro+shield&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-gbGB497GB497&oq=vance+astro+shield&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0.3450j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=Major+Victory+with+Captain+America's+shield - The mouse-over when you downvote specifically states "*does not show any research effort*"

Comment: Alright, but why answer it then?

Comment: @Secko - Boredom, and a touch of OCD.

Comment: Gotcha :) _(filling in the 15 characters)_

Comment: "*Was I lazy to search, yes. I wanted to know the answer quick so I could continue reading*" I'll never understand this. If you're after a fast answer, why wouldn't you search first before asking? If you searched and couldn't find the answer, that's one thing - but asking a question (here or anywhere else) is often likely going to require waiting for an answer when you could have already found it in a quick search of your own.

Comment: Also “I wanted to know the answer quick so I could continue reading” — that’s a bit like when you go to a movie with someone, a new character shows up, and they immediately turn to you and ask “Who’s that?” Hey, here’s an idea: if you carry on, it might well be explained.

Comment: Well, since this is Marvel - it's cluttered up between x universe and x character in x time line in x universe. If I haven't read x comic from x year with x character from x universe in x time line, I would get lost and post here as I did. I didn't think this was against the rules.